# Image not loading Http exception thrown resolving image codec

Tags: flutter

```
Image.network(
    bizLists[position].docurl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                     .size
                     .width * 0.75,
)
```

While trying to render image using image.network flutter throws codec error.

The image URL is 
http://180.12.181.8:2100/business/9c8468fb3b91ff16ab1539789bb71811.jpg

Comment: Did you managed to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the context is not valid.
context is not valid because MaterialApp (or whatever you use) is built AFTER the context therefore no MediaQuery available yet.

This also means your structure is wrong, "visible" Widgets should not be on the same class as MaterialApp.
A proposed solution would be to move your Image.network Widget to a new class.

Snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                body: MySuperJuicyImage()
            )
        );
    }
}

class MySuperJuicyImage extends StatelessWidget{
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Image.network(
            'http://180.12.181.8:2100/business/9c8468fb3b91ff16ab1539789bb71811.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that `bizLists[position].docurl` contains the correct URL? Try replacing that call with the URL you have posted. When I tired it the image rendered correctly. Give it a try.

```
    Image.network(
      'http://180.12.181.8:2100/business/9c8468fb3b91ff16ab1539789bb71811.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
    )
```

Comment: This is not the reason that it didn't run, and this answers provides 0 knowledge, it could be a comment.